# c++ vector with object pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

i have to implement a small and simple game in c++ (a maze) and I have some problems right now.

Some snippets:
I've got an array of object pointers which represents my fields in the maze

```
Field*** maze;
```

init of the maze:

```
for (n = 0; n < MAZE_WIDTH; n++) {
    this->maze[n] = new Field*[MAZE_HEIGHT];
    for (p = 0; p < MAZE_HEIGHT; p++) {
        this->maze[n][p] = new Field();
        this->maze[n][p]->x = n;
        this->maze[n][p]->y = p;
    }
}
```

When creating the maze i need a list of already visited fields and a stack
so I did:

```
std::vector<Field*> visited;
std::vector<Field*> stack;
```

Then later I want to put a Field* into my stack

```
stack.push_back(neighbour);
```

But after this push all values in the object are wrong.
Even if i try

```
neighbour = stack.back();
```

all the values are completly different

I already red some threads about this topic and that's why i chose a vector of pointers and not objects.

Where is my fault?

Edit:
Some more snippets as requested:

Of course I allocate memory for the mate itself

```
this->maze = new Field**[MAZE_WIDTH];
```

Field is a simple class which looks like:

```
class Field {
public:
    Field();
~Field();
bool w_left;
bool w_right;
bool w_front;
bool w_back;
unsigned int x;
unsigned int y;
private:
};
```

Comment: You are not by chance modifying the same Field reference every time when adding to the stack? This would cause all the values to be the same and equal to the last value added.

Comment: Could you give a little more code?  What is the type of `neighbour`, for example?  How is it initialized?  (It sounds like you might be inserting a pointer to a local variable into the `vector`, but without more code, it's impossible to tell.)

Comment: It may be the code snippet, but did you miss the `new Field**[]` at the beginning ? Also, I think there is simpler ways to handle multidimensional arrays than a pointer to a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: ¤ -1 One glaring error is that you don't allocate anything for the `maze` pointer. Another big error is having that pointer in the first place. Folks who do that are commonly to as "three srtar programmers. Use e.g. `std::vector`. Regarding what it seems that your question is about, namely why things don't work, no real answer appears to be possible given the info you present. It is in the direction of "my program does not Work, here are some unrelated bugs, what are the rest of my bugs?". Difficult to answer, to say the least. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: You should practically never need a `***` in a C program; let alone in C++.

Comment: Did you remember to initialize `maze` before you started initializing `maze[n]` and such?

Comment: See @JamesKanze comment. Show where the variable `neighbour` is declared and where it is used.

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to store field pointers in "maze"? why not just objects directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, you didn't posted the code of how you are obtaining the values, 
compare to this, and try to find your problem...

```
std::vector<std::vector<Field*> > maze;

    // Ini
    for(int i = 0; i < MAZE_WIDTH; i++)
    {
        maze.push_back(std::vector<Field*>());
        for(int j = 0; j < MAZE_HEIGHT; j++) 
        {
            maze[i].push_back(new Field());
            maze[i][j]->x = i;
            maze[i][j]->y = j;
        }
    }

    std::vector<Field*> visited;
```

// push the field [4,5] in a visited vector

```
    visited.push_back(maze[4][5]);


    // Clean up
    for(size_t i = 0; i < maze.size(); i++)
    {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < maze[i].size(); j++)      
            delete maze[i][j];      
    }
```

Comment: yeah i also ended with this solution _)

Answer (score 0):

Why declare the maze as `Field***`?

The C++ alternative is `std::vector<std::vector<Field*> > maze;`, and that's what you should use.

Comment: or, even better: `std::vector<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Field> > > maze` if C++11 is available, or with `boost::shared_ptr`/`std::tr1::shared_ptr ` instead if it isn't.

Comment: Even better: MAZE_HEIGHT and MAZE_WIDTH seems to be constant => Field maze[MAZE_WIDTH][MAZE_HEIGHT];. Then when you need to insert in vector stack.push_back(&maze[x][y]);

Comment: I declared the maze as you said but I still get the same error when I try to `stack.push_back(neighbour)`

Comment: @skelle: was neighbor allocated with new, or on the stack